# File-like object for pandas dataframe to parquet

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parquet

I want to convert my pandas df to parquet format in memory (without saving it as tmp file somewhere) and send it further over http request.

`df.to_parquet` method in pandas [says](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1.5/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html) that path can be str or file-like object: "By file-like object, we refer to objects with a write() method, such as a file handler (e.g. via builtin open function) or io.BytesIO. The engine fastparquet does not accept file-like objects."

I do not understand how can I properly create this "file-like object".

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o you can instantiate a `BytesIO` object and treat it as a file

Answer (score 2):

Passing no path to `to_parquet` will just create the bytes for you, allowing you to send it with a request without using file-like objects.

`parquet_bytes = df.to_parquet()`